# Identify a varistor

Tags: varistor, mov

I'm trying to replace these two varistors from my maytag dryer. I'm not quite sure what party they are. They look like epcos/tdk brand but not sure what the s20 k275 11 08 means, Or the other symbols. Any help is appreciated.

[image: varistors]

Answer (score 1):

S20K275, you can find the datasheet here: [SIOV metal oxide varistors | EPCOS/TDK](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/inf/70/db/var/SIOV_Leaded_StandarD.pdf)

You might have to order an equivalent from some other manufacturer but you should be set.  MOVs have largely equivalent ratings, pick equal or better from the parameters in the datasheet.

Those parts look OK, are you sure they are bad?  MOVs typically fail shorted (then catastrophically thereafter).

Comment: These are varistors, not thermistors.  They should **NOT** change value with temperature!

Comment: Thanks! They look okay, but when I test them there’s no measurement. I’ve tested all other related parts of the dryer and they’re in working order